# Android, отписка от BehaviorSubject

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

У меня есть BehaviorSubject, назначение которого - наблюдать за `int` переменной:

`private BehaviorSubject<Integer> source = BehaviorSubject.create();`

В `onCreate` я подписываюсь на него:

```
source.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                itemCounter.setText(getString(R.string.catalog_items_founded, integer));
            }
        });
```

И в коде вызываю `sourse.onNext(value)` неопределённое количество раз.

Судя по тому что я читал о RxJava, по завершению жизни Activity мне нужно от `sourse` отписаться чтобы на Activity не вели ссылки, но как это сделать? У `sourse` нет для этого метода, у `Observer` тоже, если его создавать не анонимно. Где - то я читал что можно обойтись просто `source.onCompleted();` но я не уверен в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `subscribe` возвращает объект `Subscription` или `Disposable` в зависимсоти от используемой версии `rxJava`. У этого объекта есть метод `unsubscribe` или `dispose`. Именно их и нужно использовать.

Если у вас на несколько источников идёт подписка, то можно воспользоваться контейнерами для подписок `CompositeSubscription` или `CompositeDisposable`. У них есть методы `add` и `clear` для добавления подписок и очистки контейнеров, с одновременной отпиской от источников.

Как только вы отпишетесь ссылки на источники и на активити станут доступны для очистки сборщиком мусора и возможная проблема будет решена.

В вашем случае код должен быть примерно таким (код для 2 `rxJava`):

1. В активити создаёте контейнер для подписок:

   ```
   private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
   ```
2. При создании подписки кладите её в контейнер:

   ```
   compositeDisposable.add(source.subscribe(observer));
   ```
3. В нужном методе жизненного цикла очищайте контейнер. В вашем случае, видимо, в `onDestroy`, хотя, возможно, вам лучше бы подошли бы `onResume`/`onPause` или `onStart`/`onStop`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       compositeDisposable.clear();
   }
   ```